# Create TCP socket from unmanaged file descriptor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c, sockets, ssh

I'm using an unmanaged C library, `libusbmuxd`, to create a tunnel to my phone though a USB cable. It connects to the device and returns a file descriptor socket of the connection.

```
/**
 * Request proxy connect to 
 *
 * @param handle returned by 'usbmuxd_scan()'
 *
 * @param tcp_port TCP port number on device, in range 0-65535.
 *  common values are 62078 for lockdown, and 22 for SSH.
 *
 * @return file descriptor socket of the connection, or -1 on error
 */
int usbmuxd_connect(const int handle, const unsigned short tcp_port);
```

I want to send SSH commands through it using SSH.NET, however SSH.NET only supports communication through a TCP port. How can I make a listening TCP socket from this file descriptor so I can use SSH.NET with it (e.g. `var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", "22", "mobile", authenticationMethod)`)?

I know I can make a `FileStream` object from the unmanaged file descriptor. Can I maybe use that C# object to create a socket though which SSH.NET could communicate?

Comment: Did you ever find out ?